# ASP Classic on Microsoft Edge

Tags: internet-explorer, vbscript, asp-classic, microsoft-edge

I have a website built using ASP classic which is so far running good on current browser (IE), but since the release of Windows 10 and it's Micrsoft Edge,  most of the controls (Buttons) of the websites are not working, what might be the difference in compatibility between IE and Microsoft Edge and and work arounds for the issue?

The buttons are of type VBScript.

Comment: what version of IE were you testing your website against? I'm surprised that the VBscript types are running good as you said

Comment: a follow up question would be, is your website an intranet site or will it be publicly available?

Comment: it is an intranet site

Answer (score 3):

[VBScript was deprecated](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn384057%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), and has since been removed in Edge

Answer (score 0):

Instead of forcing your legacy website to work in Microsoft Edge, prompt users to open your website in IE whenever they try to open it in Microsoft Edge.

Since your website is within the confinements of the intranet, you can use  Enterprise Mode support to Microsoft Edge by including your website in the Enterprise Mode Site List. This list can be configured by your IT Pros and be implemented as a Group Policy.

More details can be found in the MS EDge team's blog post:

https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2015/08/26/how-microsoft-edge-and-internet-explorer-11-on-windows-10-work-better-together-in-the-enterprise/